# Where are FIle.ReadAll***Async/WriteAll***Async/AppendAll***Async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, file, async-await, task-parallel-library

There are a bunch of rather convenient methods in [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, like `ReadAll***`/`WriteAll***`/`AppendAll***`.

I'm faced with a number of cases, when I need their asynchronous counterparts, but they just don't exist.

Why? Are there any pitfalls?
I know, that these methods could be easily implemented, but is there any reason to not implement them in the framework out-of-the-box?

Comment: Downvoter, any explanation?

Comment: Probably I don't understand your question, but isn't this enough? `static async Task WriteAllTextAsync(string path, string contents) { await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(path, contents)); }`

Comment: @codroipo: this is called "async over sync", and must be avoided. See this article, for example: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: @Dennis Starting from `.NET Core 2.0`, [File.WriteAllTextAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltextasync?view=netcore-2.0) method is supported.

Comment: @nam: :) The question was asked five years ago and was about .NET Framework (see the tag), not about .NET Core family. It is still relevant for .NET Framework and for people bound to this framework for some reasons. And yes, you're right about .NET Core - these methods are there.

Comment: @Dennis Agreed with the relevance of the question. Also liked your comment: "Downvoter, any explanation?" that I upvoted yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "... I need their asynchronous counterparts, but they just don't exist. Why?"

All of the `XXXAsync` methods that were added to the .Net framework together with async-await (not including new libraries developed with async in mind) are simply wrappers around `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`.

They didn't add any new asynchronous operations, they just converted old ones into new task-based ones. For example this is [`UdpClient.SendAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs,7682e0ea2c48b5cb):

```
public Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] datagram, int bytes)
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(BeginSend, EndSend, datagram, bytes, null);
}
```

Since there are no `File.BeginReadAll` and `File.EndReadAll` it's understandable that there's no `File.ReadAllAsync`.

> Are there any pitfalls?

The only pitfall with implementing these methods is doing so in a truly asynchronous manner and not faking async.

Comment: So, to rephrase your answer, "we were too lazy to do that". :)

Comment: @Dennis more like they don't add new features to old libraries (but yes...).